# Probability of Dice Rolls vs Expected Number of Dice Rolls : is there a non-mathematical explanation?

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains, dice

I have often heard a very counterintuitive problem in statistics:

Apparently, the average "number of times" (not the "probability") required to roll a dice before observing a 4 and 6 is different from the average number of times required to roll a 6 and a 6.

Although, the probability of rolling any number on the dice is equal.

Apparently, this question can be answered by creating a markov chain and it can be shown that the average number of rolls required for 4 and a 6 is soomething like "36" compared to a 6 and a 6 is "42".

Has anyone heard of this before? Is it true? Could there be any aditional explanations to why this might be true, other than the "the math just supports this conclusion"?

Thanks!

Comment: There are two stages to your wait: waiting for the first hit, then waiting for the second. The second stage is the same in either scenario: you're waiting for a certain number to come up. As for the first stage, doesn't it obviously make a difference whether you're waiting for a 4 or a 6 to come up, or just waiting for a 6?

Comment: Consider flipping a coin until heads comes up twice, vs. flipping until heads and tails have both come up. IOn the first case, half the time your first flip will be tails and you haven't made any progress. In the second case, whatever happens on the first flip, you're on your way.

Answer (score 2):

To get 6 and 6 there is only one possibility, while for 4 and 6, there are two ways depending on which came first.